# Regex to match within a string but not at the beginning

Tags: regex

I need to identify a sentence that contains the word `FUSE`.

My regex is `^(?i).* FUSE.*$`.

It is identifying sentences containing the word `FUSE`, but not if the sentence starts with `FUSE`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not recognize `FUSE` at the very beginning because your regex `^(?i).* FUSE.*$` has a space before `FUSE`. Try this:

```
^(?i).*\bFUSE\b.*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?i)` - make regex case insensitive
- `.*` - greedy scan
- `\b` - word boundary (prevents a match on for example `DIFFUSE`)
- `FUSE` - literal text
- `\b` - word boundary
- `.*` - greedy scan
- `$` - anchor at end of string

If you simply want to check if `FUSE` exists, you do not need to use anchors. This is sufficient:

```
(?i)\bFUSE\b
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having difficulties finding the right duplicate, but I'm pretty sure it's been answered before and someone will point you to the correct answer sooner or later. Untill then, I'd suggest:

```
^(?i).*(?<!\S)FUSE(?!\S).*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsJd7X/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?i)` - Set inline case-insensitive matching.
- `.*` - 0+ Characters other than newline.
- `(?<!\S)` - Assert position is not preceded by any non-whitespace character.
- `FUSE` - Literally match "FUSE".
- `(?!\S)` - Not followed by any non-whitespace character.
- `.*` - 0+ Characters other than newline.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?i)(?!FUSE).+?FUSE.*$`

explanation :

`^` strat

`(?!FUSE)` negative look ahead to make sure it's not starting with FUSE

`.+?` at least one caracter

`FUSE` your match

`.*` anything after FUSE

`$` end of the regex

Comment: I think the OP means that due to the space in the OP's tried pattern before FUSE, is does not find FUSE at the start. Your pattern specifically excludes matching FUSE at the start.